# LibGdx - Increase touch-area of Actor

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way for me to increase the touch-area of an Actor in LibGdx? In my case its a Label, I don't want to use a large button but its really hard to press the Label on the phone, so can I increase the touch area around the Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to modify the labels boundry.

Try the following method from the Actor class:

```
setBounds( float x, float y, float width, float height )
```

To dynamically set the boundry, you might be able to do something like:

```
float padding = 5f;
label.setBounds(label.getX() - padding, label.getY() - padding,
    label.getWidth() + (padding * 2f), label.getHeight() + (padding * 2f));
```